# Can't center TextView dynamically in TableRow

Tags: android, textview, center, tablerow

I have dynamically made a TableRow with an ImageButton and a TextView. 
I've set a gravity on my TableRow using `TableRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);`

Then, on my TextView, I'm using this code

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText(functie[beschrijving]);
tv.setWidth(300);
//tv.setHeight(60);
tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
tv.setPadding(15, 0, 10, 0);
tr.addView(tv);
```

When I do this, I'm getting this result. It's not quite centered, it looks like the text right below the center. Does anyone know how to put the text completely in the center?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi
I think you should use the following property of Parent Layout
android:layout_centerVertical="true"

Comment: Do you mean the TableLayout itself? Because I do this also in Java code.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this code help you.

```
android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams params = new android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams();
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
tr.addView(tv, params);
```

But I'm not sure.

Comment: It didn't help, it removed a few lines of the top pixels of the orange border.